# How can I get my notifications from Facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'd like to create an app to filter my [notifications from Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/notifications). For example I'd like to get all notifications about someone commenting in conversations I also took part on given Facebook group.

As @lushn [pointed out below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34401584/5114473), Facebook removed the ability to access notifications in their Graph API.

Now I wonder, is there a better (and more official) way to fetch notifications from Facebook than to pose as a browser and parse HTML (for that I'd also need a proxy written in some server language, due to CORS)?

Answer (score 3):

Access to notifications is not possible anymore, the required permission and the endpoint for this has been removed with v2.4 of the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

Comment: Why have you marked my question as too broad? I think it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: "can i do xy, and how?" is definitely too broad ;) - you need to state exactly what you have tried so far. you should take the tour, for future questions: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Yeah, I'd be better if I gave you some crappy and irrelewant peace of code. Access to notifications using one of Facebook APIs - don't tell me it's too broad.

Comment: that´s not what i meant, your question shows no sign of research at all > too broad. dude, questions don´t get closed for no reason, and i can´t do it alone ;)

Comment: questions should include a detailed description of what you want to achieve, AND a detailed description of what you have tried so far. that´s how it works on stackoverflow, not sure how else to explain. maybe this one helps too: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "Good: How can I redirect users to different pages based on session data in PHP?" - I think this does look similar.

Comment: i am not sure what your point is, to be honest. that question would be even worse. still WAY too broad. look, i don´t have time to argue about well known rules on SO, your question got closed by 5 different people. just include some details what you have tried so far next time.

Comment: ah, you mean the question from the howto page, my bad. maybe you should read more carefully, that´s about the title of the question only ;)